# Help On Changing Settings

Tags: settings, unknown-sources

I updated my voicemail and with out thinking I allowed  apps that are not from google play to access my phones features causing some things to disappear, on my phone How do i change my settings back to where only things from the play store and so on can be installed?

Comment: Hard to answer without details. No offense meant, but that's like asking "I broke something, how can I fix this?" We cannot tell which settings you changed, what disappeared, what apps you are referring to and what they might have done. From what you wrote, the only advice would be: factory-reset your device (which will also delete all your data and the apps you've installed), and do not install those apps again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary technique to reject applications other than from Play Store to install is in the Settings for Security. Make sure the setting "Unknown Sources" is unchecked. This setting normally allows 3rd party installation to occur.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i was looking for. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This may vary by OS version or modifications your manufacturer may have made, but the setting you're looking for is:

```
Settings | Security | Unknown sources
```

You'll want that to be unchecked to prevent apps from being installed from unofficial sources (read: the Google Play Store).

(If that's *not* what you're looking for, please edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking.)

Comment: Ha! Beat me in here by seconds!